# When I'm trying to open app it shows "Unfortunately app stops " i.e.it gets crash.So,how to resolve this?

Tags: java

E/Android Runtime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com .t p 468 .dell .automated fish pond monitoring system, P ID: 6080

j a v a .la n g .Runtime Exception: Unable to get provider

com .goo g l e .android .g ms .ads .Mobile Ads In it Provider: j a v a .la n g .Illegal State Exception:

at android .a pp .Activity Thread .install Provider(Activity Thread .j a v a: 6871)

at android .a p p .Activity Thread .install Content Providers(Activity Thread .j a v a :6463)

at android .a p p .Activity Thread .handle Bind Application(Activity Thread .j a v a :6403)

at android .a p p .Activity Thread.-wrap 5(Activity Thread .j av a)
at android .a p p .Activity Thread$H .handle Message(Activity Thread .j a v a :1887)

at android .o s .Handler .dispatch Message(Handler .j a v a :102)

at android .o s .Looper .loop(Looper .j a v a :148)

at android .a pp .Activity Thread.main(Activity Thread .j a v a :7325)

at j a v a .la n g .reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com .android .internal .o s .Zygote In it$ Method And Ar gs Caller.run(Zygote In it .j a v a :1230)

at com .android .internal .o s .Zygote In it.main(Zygote In it .j av a :1120)

Caused by: j a v a .la n g .Illegal State Exception:

Source code:

package com .t p 468 .dell .automated fish pond monitoring system;

import android .o s .Bundle;

import android .support .annotation .Non Null;

import android .support .v 7 .a pp .A pp Com pat Activity;

import android .widget .Text View;

import com .goo g l e .fire base .database .Data Snapshot;

import com .goo g l e .fire base .database .Data base Error;

import com .goo g l e .fire base .database .Data base Reference;

import com .goo g l e .fire base .database .Fire base Database;

import com .goo g l e .fire base .database .Value Event Listener;

public class Main Activity extends A pp Com pat Activity {

private Text View Ms g Text;

private Fire base Database fire base Database=Fire base Data base .get Instance();

private Data base Reference m Root Reference = fire base Database .get Reference();

private Data base Reference m child Reference = m Root Reference.child("Temperature");

@Override

protected void on Create(Bundle saved Instance State) {

```
    super .on Create(saved Instance State);

    set Content View(R.layout.activity_main);

    Ms g Text = (Text View) find View By Id(R .id .text View);

    Ms g Text .set Text("Reading Value..");
}
```

@Override

```
protected void on Start(){

    super .on Start();

    m child Reference .add Value Event Listener(new Value Event Listener() {

        @Override

        public void on Data Change(@Non Null Data Snapshot data Snapshot) {

             Integer Temperature = data Snapshot .get Value(Integer.class);

            Ms g Text .set Text(Temperature);
        }
        @Override

        public void on Ca n c el led(@Non Null Data base Error data base Error) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: pls tell me anyone??

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix the source code you have posted. There are a lot of spaces which shouldn't be there, otherwise it will result in a parse error. Also include the warning and error messages you get to your question.